# Is the matrix invertible?

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

True/False:

> If $A$ is a $m×r$  matrix with $r$ independent columns and $B$ is a $r ×n$ matrix with $r$ independent rows, then $AB$ is invertible.

I reasoned like this: Since the resultant matrix is not square, $AB$ is not invertible. Is there a better way to prove this?

Comment: How do you know that AB is not square? They don't specifically state that $m \neq n$.

Comment: True. So can I reason like this: for $A(n*r)$ and $B(r*n)$, if $r<n$ or $r>n$, then both the matrices are non invertible. So their product is non invertible too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct if $n\ne m$.

If $n=m$, then:

- If $r<n$ then it can be shown that $AB$ will have a rank of $r$ (can you show this?). Since $r<n$, $AB$ is not invertible in that case.
- If $r=n$ then $AB$ is invertible.
- The case $r>n$ is impossible (why?).

Comment: If $r<n$ then A is full column rank and rank(A)=r. We know that $rank(AB)<=rank(A)<=r$ So, AB will have a rank r. Am I correct? Can you explain why the third case is impossible?

Comment: About the last case $r>n$, is that is so, then B is full column rank, just like A, and is non invertible. Hence, AB is not invertible. Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Finally, I got it. Since in both cases ($r<n$ and $r>n$) $rank(AB)$ is not n, then there is no inverse.

Comment: In case of $n=m$, if $r<n$, then $\mathrm{rank} (AB) \le \mathrm{rank} (A) = r$, as you correctly remarked. This is enough to show that  $AB$ is not invertible, since $AB$ is not of full rank. Using [Sylvester's rank inequality] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_%28linear_algebra%29#Properties) you also get that $r+r-r \le \mathrm{rank}(AB)$, so that $\mathrm{rank}(AB) = r$.

Finally, the case $r>n$ is impossible, since by assumption $A$ has rank $r$, therefore $r$ cannot be larger than the smallest dimension of $A$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That really helped.